# Append Excel Data to SharePoint List Using PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, powerapp

I have few users who shares some data weekly using a  excel file. Each week I spend time to consolidate each excel file which takes lot of time. I am thinking that can I use PowerApps to provide an interface to the users where they will upload the excel file and the data will be appended to a Master SharePoint list?

Anyone may please suggested more better way to do this.

Regards,
Akshay

Answer (score 1):

I’m not quite sure why you need PowerApps to do that. You will need to append data from Excel to PowerApps, then save the data to SharePoint list. It seems extra work comparing to directly adding the records to SharePoint list.

But here are some references, hope they help anyway:
[How To Add Excel Data Source In Microsoft PowerApps.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-add-excel-data-source-in-microsoft-powerapps/) / [Saving data from multi screen powerapp back to sharepoint list.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Saving-data-from-multi-screen-powerapp-back-to-sharepoint-list/td-p/365261)

--

In addition, I would recommend using Power Automate (Flow) to add Excel data to a SharePoint list since it is more convenient.

See a reference here: [Import Excel data to an existing Sharepoint List.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Import-Excel-data-to-an-existing-Sharepoint-List/td-p/344866)